# Path param on class level swagger ui

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Swagger ui nor giving me field for path param provider on class levels.

```
@Path("/abc/{xyz}")
Public class Testing {

    @Get
    path("/message/{msg}")
    Public string message(){
        return "hello swagger";
    }
}
```

In swagger ui I am not getting any field for 'xyz', but for msg path param I am getting the field.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Path("/abc/{xyz}")
Public class Testing {

    @PathParam(value = "xyz")
    public String abc;

    @Get
    path("/message/{msg}")
    Public string message(){
        return "hello swagger";
    }
}
```

By using this @PathParam annotation it will be visible to Swagger UI.